# problems compiling c code with libusb on linux

Tags: c, linux, libusb

I'm trying to use libusb for a project but i'm unable to get the library working properly. Here is some source code i'm trying to compile. It doesn't do anything special. It's just a dummy program that gets the USB driver list then frees it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     struct libusb_device **devs;
     struct libusb_context *context = NULL;
     size_t list;
     size_t i;
     int ret;

   ret = libusb_init(&context);

   if(ret < 0)
      {
        perror("libusb_init");
        exit(1);
      }

   list = libusb_get_device_list(context, &devs);

   if(list < 0)
   {

       fprintf(stderr, "error in getting device list\n");
       libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
       libusb_exit(context);
       exit(1);
   }


   libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
   libusb_exit(context);

  return 0;

}
```

I compile with

gcc -o test test.c -lusb

I get the error

```
/tmp/cc2hwzii.o: in function 'main:
test.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to 'libusb_init'
test.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to 'libusb_get_device_list'
test.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to 'libusb_free_device_list'
test.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to 'libusb_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running ubuntu 14.04.3 
I've installed libusb by sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
I've searched for my header file and it is called usb.h
I've looked to make sure I have the correct flag and it's -lusb

any ideas? I'd appreciate the help. If any more information is needed just ask.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It looks like a mess.

Answer (score 6):

those `libusb_init` are included in `libusb-1.0`.
you have to install libusb-1.0-0-dev

```
$ sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
$ gcc -o test test.c -lusb-1.0
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libusb.pc` which is included in `libusb-dev` says that the version is 0.1.12

and
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc` which is included in `libusb-1.0-0-dev` says that the version is 1.0.17.

http://www.libusb.org/ says that 0.1 is legacy, and seems that API is different from 1.0.

Comment: I think you're right. Btw, what's the difference btw libusb-dev and libusb-1.0.0-dev ? Why do you know that it comes from that particular 1.0.0 package?

Comment: Thanks a lot. There are a ton of different threads about this out there and they all have different answers as to what different solutions have been. I appreciate the help I'm new to linux.

Comment: @artm I researched for the difference.

Comment: @ artm I have an arch linux machine and noticed that there's two  version of `libusb` in it, and confirm that `libusb_free_device_list` symbol is included using `nm -D libusb-1.0.so.0`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the file that defines the functions, such as libusb_init. Have you tried including libusb.h?

Comment: Isn't this covered in the usb.h file?

Comment: @MathewWright a one minute search reveals that it's `libusb.h`. http://libusb.org/static/api-1.0/files.html